# Javascript/Angular email validation method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm looking for a built in way to validate emails,
is there any typescript/angular method that is built in for email validation?
you can find 100s of regexs online for validating, but i'd like one that automatically keeps up to date with the times so to speak.

edit: just to be clear, i am not using a form, im reading emails from a csv file and validating them before sending them off to the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. Halfsies.

You can use the `@angular/forms` package and use the `Validators` class in it while using Angular's `ReactiveForms`

Then you can use the `.pattern` helper and pass an email regex to it to create a validator that returns no errors once the text matches such regex.

[here's an example](https://mailtrap.io/blog/angular-email-validation/)

---

Edit after your edit:

You can create a custom validator that internally uses the generated ValidatorFn generated by Validators.pattern and then loop through each email entry in your CSV file using some change listeners on your file input. There's no silver bullet because nobody can predict the format and position of your Email column on your CSV file so you'd need to handle that yourself.

Comment: im not using forms, im validating emails from a csv file in the front end before sending it off to the database

Comment: You can create a custom validator that internally uses the generated  `ValidatorFn` generated by `Validators.pattern` and then loop through each email entry in your CSV file using some `change` listeners on your file input. There's no silver bullet because nobody can predict the format and position of your Email column on your CSV file so you'd need to handle that yourself.